# Get WooCommerce checkout URL dynamic

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a function that lets people use a pay link to Checkout with auto log in. This works well - but my checkout url is hard coded. For using this with translated pages I need the checkout link to be dynamic.

```
wp_safe_redirect( esc_url_raw(home_url('/afrekenen/order-pay/{{'.$orderid.'}}/?pay_for_order=true&key={{'.$orderkey.'}}')));
```

I need /afreken/ to be dynamic - this is in dutch in my main language but /checkout/ in my secondary, english language.

How do I go about this?

Edit:

Solved by this:

```
$checkout_page_id = wc_get_page_id( 'checkout' );
$checkout_page_url = $checkout_page_id ? get_permalink( $checkout_page_id ) : '';
wp_safe_redirect( esc_url_raw('{{'.$checkout_page_url.'}}order-pay/{{'.$orderid.'}}/?pay_for_order=true&key={{'.$orderkey.'}}'));
```

Comment: Add another placeholder and replace it with the language.

Comment: @Mr.Jo - thanks, not sure I understand.

Comment: I mean a placeholder like {lang} for example which can be replaced when it's getting generated depending on the language.

Comment: Not sure how to fetch that part of the checkout url for a placeholder though.

Comment: I also don't know since I have no overview about your system. I can only work with the stuff u posted me. If you tell me how you get the language, I can show you how.

Comment: I use WPML, but the checkout page is the standard wooommerce checkout page.

Comment: Can you add a full URL including WPML to the question?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Can you please reply me? In case it don't works I'll find a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since I don't have a url I did some research and found out that there might be a constant with the current language. Since I don't use this plugin you need to test this by yourself:

```
if ( defined( 'ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE' ) ) {
    switch ( ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE ) {
        case 'nl':
            $checkout = 'afreken';
            break;
        case 'en':
            $checkout = 'checkout';
            break;
    }
} else {
    $checkout = 'afrekenen';
}

wp_safe_redirect( esc_url_raw( home_url( '/' . $checkout . '/order-pay/{{' . $orderid . '}}/?pay_for_order=true&key={{' . $orderkey . '}}' ) ) );
```

In the else statement I'm using a fallback if the constant is not defined. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! This would indeed work but then again im using static values. If I add a new site language I would have to update the php. Im looking for a way to dynamically fetch the WooCommerce checkout url

Comment: @user3344734 You wrote you have two languages - Dutch as main and English as second. Please edit your question. I'll try to find a solution for dynmic urls...

Comment: Yes that is correct but in the future more languages will be added - the question was to add the checkout url dynamically. This is however solved now, as you can see in my edited question. :)